# FB share shows meta description instead of page content

Tags: javascript, wordpress, facebook

I have generated my fb share button code using `Like Button Configurator`. The image and heading is showing correctly but the description showing is the meta description of my site. I need to show the first few lines of the page that I am sharing.

I have also tried with `Feed Dialog` method and try to pass the page content as description. but when I give sample text it is working but not working when I give the page content.

Also tried to set

```
<meta property="og:description"   content="Your description" />
```

but it also not worked.
All I need is to show first few lines of the sharing page instead of meta description.
[here](http://rentmesh.com/blog/rentmesh-launches-rental-advertising-platform/) is a sample page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meta tag `og:description` should work.

The issue is that Facebook cache the pages info and you need to clear the cache manually to see the changes.

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ enter your URL and see how Facebook is seeing your page info also you can force FB to fetch your new changes using the "Fetch new scrape information" button.